# Bottle / Gunicorn not responding to SIGTERM after ANY request

Tags: python, python-3.x, gunicorn, bottle

I have used Bottle for a long time and never run into this before, but recently I started a new project and encountered some strange behaviour that I just can not track down at all.

If I start a Bottle instance in my script, and send that script a SIGTERM it immediately shuts down gracefully. But if I make even a single http request any future sending of SIGTERM is shown on the screen `[INFO] Handling signal: term` but the script doesn't shut down.

I was convinced at first this was my mistake somehow, that I wasn't exiting properly from my requests, but it turns out even a 404 request, or a 405, trigger the same behaviour.

```
import bottle
bottle.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 9000, server = 'gunicorn')
```

If I run this, then send SIGTERM, no problem, script exists. If I request a page and get a 404, that's it, no more response to SIGTERM except the message saying it got the signal, but it doesn't shut down after that.

The host and port don't make any difference. Nor does adding successful requests. The only thing that seems to trigger the behaviour is the `server = 'gunicorn'` line. If I remove this, then the script acts as expected.

I kept removing more and more code trying to understand what the problem was, until I ended up with the above, and that's all it takes. Issue has to be between Bottle and Gunicorn somehow.

bottle is 0.12.25
gunicorn is 21.2.0
python is 3.10.12

Comment: Unable to reproduce on Ubuntu 22.04, Py 3.10.12, bottle==0.12.25, gunicorn==21.2.0 and your exact code (sending sigterm with [`kill -15 <pid>`](https://superuser.com/a/1519981/912226)). Output after navigating to a 404 (or not) is `[2024-01-12 13:32:24 -0800] [315196] [INFO] Handling signal: term; Worker exiting (pid: 315197); Shutting down: Master`

Comment: @ggorlen how long did you wait before sending SIGTERM? I noticed if I wait 30 seconds after any request the worker eventually has a critical error and then responds to SIGTERM.

Comment: No difference--I  waited 5 minutes or so before sending the sigterm, and tried it again, doing it instantly. There are no worker errors.

Comment: @ggorlen ok, that won't show the problem because after 5 minutes the worker is already closed. I just tried it again in a completely fresh venv, with nothing installed but bottle and gunicorn and the same thing happens. 30 seconds after the 404 gunicorn outputs `[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT` and starts the worker over.